# Jenkins Promoted build

Tags: jenkins

I don't understand what Promoted build really is and how it works. Can someone please explain to me like to a 10 years old kid. If you can provide some sample examples would help me a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a typical software developing organization with CI system, there are 10's or 100's of **continuous builds** daily. Only **one** of those builds (usually the latest stable) is selected and "promoted" to be a **Release Candidate (RC)**, which goes to the next quality gate - usually the QA department. Then, they select one of those RC's (others are dropped) and again, "promote" it to the next level - either to staging environment, validation etc. Then, finally... one of these builds is again "promoted" to be an **official release**.

Why is that important?

- *Visibility*: You would want to distinguish many "regular", continuous builds from few, selected "RC" builds.
- *Retention*: If you commit often (which is the best practice), you will likely get lot of daily builds, and would like to implement a retention policy (e.g. only keep last 100 builds or only builds from the last 7 days). You will then want to make sure promoted builds (RCs) are locked against retention. This is mostly important if you deploy binaries to customers, and may need the exact binary to reproduce an escaping bug in the future (though you still have the source code in the repository, I've seen cases where escaping bugs relate to the build process rather than the source code - due to rapid changes to the build process, or time-of-build sensitive data like digital signatures).
- *Permissions*: you may want to prevent access to builds with "half baked" features from non-developers.
- *Binary Repositories*: you may want to publish only meaningful builds to an external binary repository.

Builds in Jenkins can be "promoted" either manually or automatically, using plugins like [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). You can also create your entire "promotion" workflow using pipeline scripts. Here's an example:

- a "Continuous" job that polls SCM and builds on every change. It has a retention policy to keep only the last 50 builds. Access is restricted only to developers;
- a "Release Candidates" job that copies artifacts from a manually selected build (using parameters). Access is allowed to QA testers;
- a "Releases" jobs that copies artifacts from a manually selected RC. Access is allowed to the entire organization. Binaries are released to external/public repository.

I hope this answers your question :-)